# How do I override inline CSS with !important value?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing a website on WordPress. I want to override an inline CSS rule to style the menu in mobile. Problem is, the inline rule has !important value. I believe the inline styles is being generated dynamically.

Inline styles:

```css
.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu{
  background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

[Inline rule result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUwxO.png)

Here is the external style

```css
.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu{
  background-color: RGBA(10,14,13,0.9) !important;
  }
```

[External rule result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwIWx.png)

I have read that you can use JavaScript to override the inline rule, but am not sure where to post the JavaScript post.

Your insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Ew. Inline styles **AND** they're `!important`. That's gotta be a sin. The author of this theme should be given a slap on the wrist. It is possible to override that with a specific enough selector, but it would be really ugly since inline styles have a specificity of 1000, and thus you'd need an incredibly long nasty selector. You can change the inline style in Javascript with `element.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: make sure that your !important rule load after wordpress ... for example, create your own CSS file and include it after all worpdress CSS

Comment: ps. It think that you do not understand "inline style"

Comment: @David where exactly in the code would I place the Javascript?

Comment: @Wordica I have a child theme which has its own stylesheet and it loads after the CSS of the main theme. Since the rule here is inline, it overrides my stylesheet.

Comment: then make it after DOM loaded in JS. Clear style='' and add Your own

Answer (score 0):

In Js ... but You must know how and when include JS in function.php

```
$(window).on("load", function() {

    $(body).find('.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu 
                  .et_mobile_menu).removeAttr("style");
    
    $(body).find('.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu 
                  .et_mobile_menu).css('background-color',"rgba(10,14,13,0.9)")
});
```

If RGBA won't work, just add color hex.